# object aid class diagram save to jpeg

Tags: java, eclipse, objectaid

I've just created a class diagram of my code and I'd like to export it to an external jpeg or other img format to put in a report. However, I can't see how to do this. Can anyone tell me where ? I've tried right click on it -> export but there are no image formats there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: I deleted it and when you create it again you can select to automatically save to an image

Comment: Without license how can I export it? Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 9):

May be old, still am using below option to convert/save .ucls file to jpeg

Open the .ucls file in eclipse that you have created, right click "Automatic Image" then select the option.

With this as and when you save ucls file changes, an automatic image file will be created

[image]

Answer (score 5):

"Window"->"Preferences"->"ObjectAid"->"Class Diagram"
You can select "Save Image with Diagram".

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Open the .ucls file that you have created. Right Click on an empty space and select the option "Save as image". Then you can save it in any of the image formats - GIF / JPEG / PNG.